# Import Image for Navigation Header

Tags: android, image, navigation-drawer, photoshop, vector-graphics

I try to import an image for a header of my Navigation Drawer Activity. I do not use Illustrator and only got Photoshop. I tried several dimensions but the image in the navigation drawer is always small. Also it seems like the new Image Asset I import has to be a square because when the image is too long it just cuts it off.

The image contains only a text edited via Photoshop.

How can I import and / or create the image properly so it is shown nice and big in the nav header?

Answer (score 0):

In the Navigation Drawer layout xml file. Above `DrawerView` and inside your parent layout add an `Image view`:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:src="respective_source_of_image" />
```

Comment: I know this but what about the size of the image?